# Orbeon deployment in DMZ server

Tags: orbeon

We are facing following issue:

- We have deployed Orbeon in DMZ server, which is Ubuntu virtual machine (Internal IP Address: x.x.x.x). And the public IP address for this server is y.y.y.y

  - DMZ server is configured to not to access the public IP inside from the server itself.
  - The Orbeon form submission use public IP (y.y.y.y). So, we are getting "request timed out" error.

So, it is possible to change the configuration in Orbeon from to use internal IP (x.x.x.x) address while on submission. If yes, how to do that?

Please help to resolve this issue.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change it with this property:

```
<property
  as="xs:anyURI"
  name="oxf.url-rewriting.service.base-uri"
  value="http://x.x.x.x/orbeon"/>
```